# Bootstrap input controls width issue inside a form

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my ASP.NET MVC Core project I'm unable to increase the width of the input controls inside a form. I tried adding the attribute `width=500px` etc to input controls but it always display the same fixed width of the input controls as shown in the image below.

**Note**: I'm using the latest ASP.NET Core and VS2015 versions that, by default, have bootstrap 3 installed.

**Display of the View**:

[image]

**View**:

```
@model myProj.Models.SystemEmail
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
        @await Component.InvokeAsync("LeftMenu")
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <form asp-action="SysEmailEdit">
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <hr />
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="SystemEmailId" />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="From" class="col-md-1 control-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-md-11">
                        <input asp-for="From" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="From" class="text-danger" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="EmailSubject" class="col-md-1 control-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-md-11">
                        <input asp-for="EmailSubject" class="form-control" width="500px" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="EmailSubject" class="text-danger" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="EmailBody" class="col-md-1 control-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-md-11">
                        <textarea asp-for="EmailBody" class="form-control"/>
                        <span asp-validation-for="EmailBody" class="text-danger" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-11">
                        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div>
            <a asp-action="SystemEmails">Back to List</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look inside **/Content/site.css**.
Microsoft added this and if you remove, its fixed:

```
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```

Also, you can overwrite the max-width:

```
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: none;
}
```

Comment: max-width:500px etc worked (thank you). But please note max-width does not have value of auto. It has only: inherit, initial, none, unset [See here for Ref](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp). You may want to update your response (by removing/replacing auto) and I'll mark it as answer.

Comment: @nam Yep, you are right. It's "none". I've updated it.